# How to debug an http request in Apache Camel

Tags: https, apache-camel

Is there a way to log or debug the http header values? I see how to log the Camel headers, but I have a GET request that isn't working, and I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the headers I need to send for authentication. I have a method called generateSignature, which is working as far as the camel header values appear.

```
from("timer:hello?period={{timer.period}}")
    .routeId("pollOrderStatus")
    .log("${header.CamelMessageTimestamp}")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.GET))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .setHeader("US-KEY", constant("12345"))
    .setHeader("US-TS").exchange(exchange -> {
        return exchange.getMessage().getHeader("CamelMessageTimestamp");
    })
    .setHeader("US-SIGN").exchange(exchange -> {

        try {
            String sig = this.generateSignature("ABCDEF", 
                    (long) exchange.getMessage().getHeader("US-TS"), 
                    "GET", "https://host.us/api/orders/history?market=USD", null);
            return sig;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
    })
    .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    .to("https://host.us/api/orders/history?market=USD")    
    .log("${body}");
}
```

In the output, the Camel headers are correct:

```
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, Headers: {
CamelHttpMethod=GET, 
CamelMessageTimestamp=1637276749278, 
Content-Type=application/json, 
firedTime=Sat Nov 20 09:48:29 EST 2021, 
US-KEY=12345, 
US-SIGN=aa17goodlookingsig, 
US-TS=1637276749278}, 
BodyType: null
```

But I get a 401 error from the API, which makes me think the Camel headers aren't maybe making it to the http headers.

Comment: If you are seeing a 401 then Camel is working and the Web Server is responding with 401.  You probably need to check how to auth against the rest endpoint. Try getting it to run in PostMan/Insomnia etc first.

Comment: @Namphibian I have. I have this working on PostMan, cURL, and Python. I even used WireShark. I switched Camel to use http (so the headers wouldn't encrypt) and I see the headers are filled out. I don't see what the difference is in Camel's request that it's getting the 401 compared to everything else I've tried.

Comment: I dont see " accept" header in the Camel headers you dumped. Postman would have filled that  in at least.  Any HTTP return codes is from the Web Server, Camel will never issue a 401,500 or any HTTP code by itself that will come from the web-server. If Camel cannot talk to the server you will see a connection exception not a HTTP return code. IN short the route is reaching out to the web server and sending a request it is getting denied.  You can also add a log statement to the end of your route, You should see that the web servers filled in some values.

Comment: Just a thought but it could be that the signature header is not correct. Can you use one from Postman that is working and then just add it as a constant?

Comment: I know the signature is correct. I logged it with Camel and quickly fed it to Postman, which gave a success and correct payload. I've also tried adding and not adding Accept and Content-Type. There's something about the Camel request that the API doesn't like. I tried logging at the end like this .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")  Is there a way to get the actual http request being generated?

Comment: Is there a way you can ask the owners of the web server/rest service if they can see what is wrong with the request? I have done 100's of REST integrations with Camel and never had issues with a GET request.  If you are logging the header and the body you are logging the HTTP request GET's normally dont have bodies(there are exceptions) Are you behind a proxy? Is there an issue wit the certificates? How do you authorize? Really wish I could be more useful.

Comment: You could also set `throwExceptionOnFailure` to `false` and handle response codes equal or higher than 400 manually. This way you can easily get the response body sent by the server and log it to see proper server response. Dunno if you can somehow get the response with `throwExceptionOnFailure` set to `true`.

Comment: You could use tcpmon (https://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/) to proxy the requests and compare requests from postman and camel.